# I have a jar of Hannah's Pickled Sausages. What now?

Tags: meat

Having never eaten a Pickled Sausage and yet I now have a jar of Hannah's Pickled Sausages. What now?

I have never been severed any in my neighborhood but I had no qualms about picking it up in some store when I was out of state. Is it intended to be eaten like a quarter pickle on the side of a sandwich? OR maybe as sliced pickles simple as a condiment? Is it used on a bun like a hot dog as the meat item? Is it used in a casserole recipe with onions and sauerkraut? If the answer to any of these is yes, I will note that I have not found recipes listing them.

[image: Hannah's Pickled Sausages]

Comment: Eat them?  Is there something serious you are trying to ask?

Comment: I have no pickled sausages. What now? ;-)

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ, yes. Added a bit to question.

Comment: I think it is just bar food.  You just eat them.

Comment: It's *sausage*. Is there some reason to believe that it's different from any other sausage? This reads a lot like a recipe request to me - see the [culinary uses guidelines](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/740/41).

Comment: @Aaronut, the reference to recipes was just an example of what might be useful. "they are just like any other sausage" could be the answer. Pickled and not pickled cucumbers have different uses.

Comment: @Aaronut from culinary uses guidelines: "When the ingredient in question is rare or unusual ... will probably be more informative to people"

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII I am closing this question. The ingredient is *not* unusual in many cultures, and it is used just as any other sausage. So the possible pool of answers is endless, and not especially interesting - exactly what the culinary uses guidelines guard against.

Comment: @rumtscho pickled and un-pickled cucumbers are in general treated differently. If in fact is "is used  just like any other sausage" that would be a reasonable answer that could compete for up votes and the check mark. Are there any guidelines for "not unusual in many cultures"? I did not just head to this stackexchange before using google. If there were easily accessible then typically someone would have jumped on it and posted answers.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this exact brand many times at parties ... we just snacked on the whole sausages, but you could also cut it and eat it as a quarter pickle. But I can imagine it also working in a sandwich or on a bun if you don't like them straight, but we mostly just ate them as they are. A nice little refreshing snack, especially great after some drinking.

*Dishes that I had with pickled sausages:*

I have had pickled sausage as a **salad**, cut in slices mixed with sliced onion and drizzled with a little bit of oil. Served just with a little bit of rye bread on the side.

Diced very small they can give **mashed potatoes** an extra twist ... when I had them in mashed potatoes we also added some fresh dill and diced boiled carrots. It was delicious. But in the same way, adding a little bit of sourness, I can imagine it being also nice in a hearty potato casserole.

I hope this gives you some ideas. I think the best is to taste it, now that you know you can just eat it straight, and then you will maybe think of something you would like it with most.